How should I should prove $\mathbb{R}\sim\{0,1\}^{ \mathbb{N}}$
I've seen some argument about the binary representation, but I think it is not accurate because under some extreme cases, the rounding or bit constraint would results distinct reals also have the same binary representation.
What I came up with so far, I can only show the injection $f$ as following, $\mathbb{R}\sim(0,1)$ and the element in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence with terms $0$ and $1$
\begin{align*}
f:&\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\to (0,1)\\
&\{f(n)\}_n\mapsto 0.f(1)f(2)f(3)\ldots
\end{align*}
But I have no idea about how to show injection $g:\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. I would be appreciate to see the proposed mapping preserve the domain ($\mathbb{R}$ or $(0,1)$) and codomian $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.
Please help.

Hint: the set of points where $f$ fails to be injective is counterable.

@LidingYao Thank you for your reply. I agree with this statement, but I have no idea how  does it related to show $g$
